# Sharepoint 2010 - Problem with event handlers for dynamically created controls

Tags: events, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

In a WebPart using Sharepoint 2010, I´ve got a problem when creating dynamically a LinkButton because his event isn´t fired.

My code is:

Default.aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="formAccountCode" runat="server" MaxLength="8" Columns="8"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Table ID="idTabela" runat="server" Width="100%" BorderWidth="1px" GridLines="Both"></asp:Table>
<asp:Button ID="btPesquisar" runat="server" onclick="btPesquisar_Click" Text="Pesquisar" />
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void btPesquisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lkButton = new LinkButton();
    lkButton.Text = "Teste Tabela";
    lkButton.ID = "link1";
    lkButton.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
    lkButton.CommandArgument = "Codigo 1";
    lkButton.Command += test;

    TableRow tr;
    TableCell td1; 

    td1 = new TableCell();
    td1.Controls.Add(lkButton);

    tr = new TableRow();
    tr.Cells.Add(td1);
    idTabela.Rows.Add(tr);

    idTabela.DataBind();
}

protected void test(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    formAccountCode.Text = "HI"; // just for test
}
```

The idea is return a select from DB and create a result with linkbutton to each record returned.

These LinkButtons will be created after an action from the user, because this, it can´t be created in OnInit.

They will connect with another web part.

Answer (score 1):

please move the code for dynamically created button and event handler in `CreateChildControls()` and call the `EnsureChildControls()` in `Onload`

For example:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    base.CreateChildControls();

    // Create our drop down list, but don't populate it yet
    _dropDownList = new DropDownList();
    this.Controls.Add(_dropDownList);
}
```